# Navigate on keypress over array of divs javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
  <div id="wrapper">
    <img class="seperator selected" src="imgs/character_1.png" tabindex="0" />
    <img class="seperator" src="imgs/character_2.png" tabindex="0" />
    <br />
    <img class="seperator" src="imgs/character_3.png" tabindex="0" />
    <img class="seperator" src="imgs/character_4.png" tabindex="0" />
    <br />
    <img class="seperator" src="imgs/character_5.png" tabindex="0" />
    <img class="seperator" src="imgs/character_6.png" tabindex="0" />
  </div>
```

So i'm listening to `keypress` and if it's `keyCode === 32` which is the space bar, move the `selected` class one across. So I can do `thisIndex++` and increment up by `+1` everytime space is pressed but how do I target that element add a class and remove the previous one? I get `addClass is not a function` error.

```
$("body").on("keydown", function(e) {

  var thisIndex = $(".selected").index();
  var newIndex = null;

  if (e.keyCode === 32) {
    $(".seperator").removeClass("selected");

    thisIndex++;
    $('.seperator').get(thisIndex).addClass("selected");
  }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) method returns DOM object so you can't use jQuery [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass) method on it, instead use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) method to get jQuery object based on index.

```
$('.seperator').eq(thisIndex).addClass("selected");
```

---

You can combine all the lines inside the if into one by chaining the methods.

```
$(".seperator").removeClass("selected").eq(thisIndex + 1).addClass("selected");
```

---

**UPDATE :** You need to get index within the `img` tag collection(with class `seperator`) otherwise index calculated including the `br` tag.

```js
$("body").on("keydown", function(e) {
  // specify the collection as the argument
  var thisIndex = $(".selected").index('.seperator');

  if (e.keyCode === 32)
    $(".seperator")
    .removeClass("selected")
    .eq(thisIndex + 1)
    .addClass("selected");

});
```

```css
.selected {
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <img class="seperator selected" src="imgs/character_1.png" tabindex="0" />
  <img class="seperator" src="imgs/character_2.png" tabindex="0" />
  <br />
  <img class="seperator" src="imgs/character_3.png" tabindex="0" />
  <img class="seperator" src="imgs/character_4.png" tabindex="0" />
  <br />
  <img class="seperator" src="imgs/character_5.png" tabindex="0" />
  <img class="seperator" src="imgs/character_6.png" tabindex="0" />
</div>
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense! Thank you! Did you notice anything off with the way I'm incrementing? On `keypress` it seems to increment as such, `1` `2` `4` `7`. I tried incrementing up `thisIndex+=1;` instead of `thisIndex++`

Comment: Thank you! I thought since I was only targeting the selected class `$(".selected").index();` that incrementing up would just add one but your answer makes perfect sense. Thanks again :)